# vb.net : send an email with sensitivity label

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office365, office-automation, azure-information-protection

i have an application at work  which creates a new html mail message,trough the outlook client on my pc.
the security policy wants me to set sensibility label each mail.
i tried with this code but it doesn't work,cause the new mail message comes up without the sensitivity label.is there anybody can help me ? i don't have access do admin configuration/powershell or whatever..
thanks

```
Try
Dim Outlook_App As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
Dim Outlook_Message As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem




            Outlook_Message = Outlook_App.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            Outlook_Message.Sensitivity = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSensitivity.olConfidential

            Outlook_Message.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            Outlook_Message.Subject = "Orientamento treno " & numerotreno & " del " & Today.ToShortDateString
            Outlook_Message.HTMLBody = emailTemplate



            Outlook_Message.To = "fminervini@e646.it"
            'con questa procedeura faccio inviare la mail dall'account che corrisponde a quest'indirizzo

            Dim account As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Account

            For Each account In Outlook_App.Session.Accounts
                If account.DisplayName = "m.minervini@e646.it" Then

                    Outlook_Message.SendUsingAccount = account
                    Outlook_Message.Sensitivity = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSensitivity.olConfidential
                End If
            Next

            Outlook_Message.Display(False)
```

Answer (score -1):

The [MailItem.Sensitivity](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) property returns or sets a constant in the [OlSensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsensitivity) enumeration indicating the sensitivity for the Outlook item. That is a pure Outlook label and not related to [Sensitivity labels and Azure Information Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/sensitivity-labels#sensitivity-labels-and-azure-information-protection).

You need to add a user property in the following format:

```
"MSIP_Label_" & guid_internal_use_only & "_Enabled"
```

Look for the `UserProperties.Add` method for such tasks.

But I'd suggest exploring internals of Outlook mail items using [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or `OutlookSpy` to find the exact solution. Try to set it manually then explore internals using these tools.

Comment: may be you can help me to understand (my english is not so good).i work in a company so i can't add software to outlook or enter the admin panel.

Comment: Try to set any sensitivity label manually in Outlook and then try to explorer internals to figure out the GUID that need to be used in the code (see the sample string).

Comment: well it's not so clear but i try.thanks for your help

Comment: You need to use the [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) method for adding AIP labels.

Comment: but @Eugene Astafiev how does it work userproperties.add... and then ? how can i add a label ??

Comment: The format of the property value is described in my post. Try to use any low-level property explorer such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Okay, so that clearly can't be the UserProperty *name*, since Property Names cannot contain underscores.  That means it must be a Value... but with what Name?  (Also, your header detail is incomplete anyway, because you haven't established whether `Enabled` is True or False, nor what the `SiteID` and `ContentBits` are)  I'm guessing you never actually tested/verified your supposed 'solution'?

Comment: I heard so many time similar phrases like `you never tried`, but try to imagine how many responses I post and you think I need to keep in my head everything that i have tried so far? As I have already suggested, try using any low-level explorer utility such MFCMAPI to realize the format. Microsoft doesn't disclose everything per your needs.